# How do I calculate an SVG path of an arc using data?

Tags: javascript, svg

In theory I have a circular gauge that fills after "x" amount of time goes by.

I'm currently building out a web app and I have my circular arc working for debugging purposes, What I need to do now is to apply attributes so I can track the circular gauge within the app when users in our app log in.

How can I achieve this so when users log in they see they have "x" amount of time left in this circular gauge?

JS below:

```
function describeArc(radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

function polarToCartesian(radius, angle) {
    return {
        x: radius * Math.cos(angle),
        y: radius * Math.sin(angle),
    };
}

var start = polarToCartesian(radius, endAngle);
var end = polarToCartesian(radius, startAngle);

var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= Math.PI ? 0 : 1;

// Generate the SVG arc descriptor.
var d = [
    'M', start.x, start.y,
    'A', radius, radius, 1, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
].join(' ');

return d;
}

let arc = 0;

setInterval(function() {
// Update the ticker progress.
arc += Math.PI / 1000;
if (arc >= 2 * Math.PI) { arc = 0; }

// Update the SVG arc descriptor.
let pathElement = document.getElementById('arc-path');

pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));
}, 400 / 0)
```

I'm left scratching my head since I'm newer to SVG and JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current `arc` value into `localStorage`, so you can retrieve it later on like this

```
function describeArc(...) { ... }

let arc = localStorage.arc ? parseFloat(localStorage.arc) : 0;

setInterval(function() {
  // Update the ticker progress.
  arc += Math.PI / 1000;
  if (arc >= 2 * Math.PI) { arc = 0; }

  // Update the SVG arc descriptor.
  let pathElement = document.getElementById('arc-path');

  pathElement.setAttribute('d', describeArc(26, 0, arc));

  // Persist the current arc value to the local storage
  localStorage.setItem('arc', arc);
}, 400 / 0) // Divided by 0?
```

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thank you sir!